Error: no client jwks provided for signing a client assertion with Zitadel and openid-client
I am using Zitadel as an Identity Provider, and created there a project and an API with a key. I now want to obtain a M2M token through the “JWT bearer token with private key” method, which is the recommended way for M2M tokens according to Zitadel (click). I use the following code and the library openid-client to do so:
/* tslint:disable:no-console */
import { exportJWK, importPKCS8, SignJWT } from 'jose';
import { Issuer } from 'openid-client';
import NodeRSA from 'node-rsa';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const getToken = async () => {
    const clientId = '27700000000000000';

    // Step 1: Discover the OpenID Connect provider's configuration
    const oidcIssuer = await Issuer.discover('https://xxxxxx-xxxxxx.zitadel.cloud');

    // Step 2: Create a JWK from the private key
    const keyJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '27700000000000001.json'), 'utf8'));
    const rsa = new NodeRSA(keyJson.key);
    const key = await importPKCS8(rsa.exportKey('pkcs8-private-pem'), 'RSA256');
    const jwk = await exportJWK(key);

    // Step 3: Create a new client with the JWK
    const client = new oidcIssuer.Client({
            client_id: clientId,
            token_endpoint_auth_method: 'private_key_jwt',
        }, {
            keys: [jwk]
        }
    );

    // Step 4: Generate a JWT signed with the private key
    const jwt = await new SignJWT({
        iss: clientId,
        sub: clientId,
        aud: oidcIssuer.metadata.token_endpoint
    })
        .setIssuedAt()
        .setExpirationTime('5m')
        .setProtectedHeader({
            alg: 'RS256',
            kid: keyJson.keyId
        })
        .sign(key);

    // Step 5: Exchange the JWT for an access token
    const tokenSet = await client.grant({
        grant_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
    }, {
        clientAssertionPayload: {
            client_assertion_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer',
            client_assertion: jwt
        }
    });

    console.log('Access Token:', tokenSet.access_token);
};

getToken();

Things work well until step 5. When running this, I get this error:
OPError: invalid_request (assertion missing)

I don't see which assertion is missing, I am giving it in step 5. What am I missing?

I would first make sure that you are in control of the POST payload. For example, you might use node-fetch like this:
const formData = new URLSearchParams();
formData.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
formData.append('client_assertion', assertion);
formData.append('client_assertion_type', 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer');

const response = await fetch(tokenEndpointUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'accept': 'application/json',
    },
    body: formData,
});

If using a library, make sure you can log or trace the raw HTTP request sent, to ensure that it matches the above format.
Note that private_key_jwt is a token endpoint authentication method. You might first try it in a simple flow like client_credentials when getting the POST working. That is also usually the correct M2M flow.
Note that the grant urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer is a user assertion and indicates that a user is present. It is sometimes used to exchange an access token from another identity system.
The public key (or the location of a JWKS URI that you provide) should be registered in the authorization server against your trusted client, not sent in the request (since that might enable a malicious client to gain access).
